# S3 module for downloading files is not working in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible, boto

This is the ansible code written for downloading files from S3 bucket "artefact-test".

```
 - name: Download customization  artifacts from S3
   s3:
      bucket: "artefact-test"
      object: "cust/gitbranching.txt"
      dest: "/home/ubuntu/"
      mode: get
      region: "{{ s3_region }}"
      profile: "{{ s3_profile }}"
```

I have set the boto profile and aws profile too. I get different errors which i dont think are valid like -

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmittal/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462436903.77-107775915578620/s3", line 2320, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/dmittal/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462436903.77-107775915578620/s3", line 304, in main
    ec2_url, aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, region = get_ec2_creds(module)
  File "/home/dmittal/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462436903.77-107775915578620/s3", line 2273, in get_ec2_creds
    region, ec2_url, boto_params = get_aws_connection_info(module)
  File "/home/dmittal/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462436903.77-107775915578620/s3", line 2260, in get_aws_connection_info
    if not boto_supports_profile_name():
  File "/home/dmittal/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462436903.77-107775915578620/s3", line 2191, in boto_supports_profile_name
    return hasattr(boto.ec2.EC2Connection, 'profile_name')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ec2'

failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true}
msg: Target bucket cannot be found

failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true}
msg: Target key cannot be found
```

Whereas the bucket and key specified both exists on AWS.The same thing works if i use AWS-CLI commands to do the same.

Comment: Where do you store the acces and secret keys?

Comment: Should your bucket name be "artifact-test" instead of "artifact-test"?

Comment: what version of Ansible and what version of Boto do you have installed?

Comment: @PumpkinSeed : Usually i keep it here "~/.aws/credentials" and workd for all modules but for this i even create ~/.boto to store access key and secrets.

Comment: @CarsonCole:   The bucket name is same which exists on AWS and which is mentioned in the code.I tried for different buckets too.

Comment: @tedder42 : ansible 1.9.4 and boto 2.38.0

Comment: There's something really wrong with your boto install.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11755#issue-97527714) related to this. You might want to try adding the following import statement in the file `ansible/module_utils/ec2.py` -

```
import boto.ec2
```

Something like this - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9cf43ce17f20171b5740a6e0773f666cb47e2d5e/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py#L31