# Python 3.5 Type Hinting Factory Type

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-3.5, boto3

If I create a connection to aws-ec2 using boto3, it has return type `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.ServiceResource`

```
import boto3
cnxn = boto3.Session().resource('ec2')
type(cnxn)
>>  boto3.resources.factory.ec2.ServiceResource
```

I'd like to be able to use this as a type for type hinting. However, if I try to reference it, I get an error.

```
boto3.resources.factory.ec2.ServiceResource
AttributeError: module 'boto3.resources.factory' has no attribute 'ec2'
```

Is there any way to use these types as hints?

Edit: importing also doesn't work

```
import boto3.resources.factory.ec2
>> ImportError: No module named 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2'; 'boto3.resources.factory' is not a package
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to do `import boto3.resources.factory.ec2`?

Comment: That gives an ImportError – see edit.

Comment: How about `import boto3.ec2` (as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045947/s3-module-for-downloading-files-is-not-working-in-ansible))?  If you google for that AttributeError message you'll find various pages where people have encountered similar errors; some of those might help you.

Comment: State the reason why you want to "reference" the type? You cannot reference a type. Even to know whether an variable belongs to particular type, I just use expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), as those types don't exist until runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to python [type documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

What you get is a type object.  If your intention is to create a new object out of the type, then use `class type(name, bases, dict)` to create a new object. AS show in the example :

```
>>> class X(object):
...     a = 1
...
>>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```